# Custom authenticator for 2FA with lighttpd

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd, http-authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have a web application which currently uses lighttpd with mod_auth and the htdigest method for authentication. I want to expand the web apps functionality to allow for 2FA. If I understand correctly, what happens for htdigest authentication is the following:

1. The browser requests a website from the server
2. The server responds with "authentication required"
3. The browser shows the user a window asking for username/password and sends this information to the server
4. The server serves the webpage

If I understand correctly, the server caches this auth info and automatically sends it for following requests.

Now, I want to add 2FA. I found out that I can use fastcgi to build a custom authorizer. Can I use this to do 2FA? How can I ask the browser to provide the user with a possibility to enter the OTP? It's no use to cache the OTP and send it with every request, so I guess I need to store a session token or something which the browser should send with every following request?

Comment: Please see discussion at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/426
and a session-based implementation https://github.com/gstrauss/lighttpd-mod_authn_tkt (which would follow your custom FastCGI authorizer)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for <3